# Elasticsearch log results/queries

Tags: elasticsearch

i am just using elasticsearch for my new shop-search. It works fine and very fast!
I am using nginx/PHP and the PHP-Connector. 
Now i wanted to log all queries and the total.hits in a "log"-index. 
I tryed to insert the data via PHP-Insert to elastic-log-index, but this was to slow... mostly a search now takes  160ms instead of 80ms.....
is there a possibility to log queries/results faster to a elasticsearch-index? Otherwise i write the data to a small txt/csv and via cronjob to Elastic, but this is not live and not comfortable....
thanks in advance!

Comment: check Logstash maybe? https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash